# Time series question from book (ma)

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I'm trying to understand this subject and  I'm stuck in a question found in a book. [image]

I understand white noise characterization, but I'm having some problems with this... maybe it's too much theory? I kind of get lost when I try to prove that also the new variable $Y$ is MA, and don't get me started on solving for the parameters. Maybe some hints on how to proceed or explain the steps I need to follow?

Comment: What definition of an MA(1) process are you working with?  Whatever it is would be an excellent place to begin.

Comment: Well I'm defining MA(1) as $Y_t = \mu + e_t + \theta e_{t-1}$. (From one of the books in my class, Time Series Analysis, J.Hamilton). It is shown that from this formula we can say that the first autocovariance is $\gamma _1 = \theta \sigma^2$ and all of the other  autocovariances beyond the first lag are all zero. From here I'm not really sure how to continue...

Comment: Maybe by recalling one of  the three properties of a white noise, i.e $\mathbb{E}(e_t) = 0$, $\gamma _0 = \mathbb{E} ( e_t^2)= \sigma^2$ and $ \gamma _j = \mathbb{E}(e_t e_{t-j}) =0, \ \ \forall j \neq 0$??

Comment: The hint guides you towards computing the relevant covariances for $(Y_t)$ using those properties of white noise.